# How to get data from other model in a controller in Laravel 4

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm developing a small project in Laravel 4 and I need to check if the user completed a task.
When the user complete a task, a record is inserted in "certificates" table, with his user_id and the number of the section he completed.

In the index of the sections, I need to enable only those sections he completed and the current one.
How can I get all the user certificates in the certificates table in the controller? 
In other words, how can I select all the items with the user_id on certificates table, in the "sections" controller/model?

The function in the section controller is:

```
  public function getIndex() {
    $items = Item::orderBy('id','asc')->paginate(0);
    return View::make('home')->with('items', $items);
  }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at [this section of the docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#relationships)

Comment: You do need some tutorial before the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have `users`, `certificates` and `sections` tables and corresponding models (at least `User` and `Section`), and your `certificates`-table has a `user_id` and a `section_id`, you'd use a many-to-many relationship:

```
class User extends Eloquent
    {
        public function sections()
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany('Section', 'certificates');
        }
    }
```

Now, you can access `$user->sections`, which will give you a collections that the user completed (assuming that's what you use the `certificates`-table for). What it does is basically take the id of `user`, look it up in the `certificates`-table in the `user_id` column, take all the `section_ids`, look up those in the `sections`-table and return a collection of model instances corresponding to the resulting rows.

Comment: It works! But because of some business rules, I changed to other way.

In the getIndex function in my controller I changed to: 
$items = Item::join('certificados', 'items.id', '=', 'certificados.item_id' )->where('certificados.user_id', '=', $userDetails->id)->orderBy('items.id','asc')->paginate(0);

Now I guess it's more flexible to change if some rule changes. 
BTW, thank you for the help! :)

Comment: I guess it is, yes. You're welcome! May I ask why you do `paginate(0)`?

Comment: Well, paginate(0) do the same as get() ?
I guess it was paginate(10) but I changed to zero only for test propose.